# Tags for which there is no tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Is it possible to view list of tags for which there is no tag wiki? I.e. those for which we see the text:

"There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet! "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a very simple [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/368139/tags-without-wikis) to find tags without a tag wiki.

```
select tagName, count
from tags
where wikiPostId is null
order by count desc
```

This returns 11879 tags as of 24 September 2015.

Comment: It seems quite a lot of them...

Comment: Yeah, I was also surprised.  I knew we had a lot of tags, but not that many just without descriptions.

Comment: Not sure what is the reason of having tag with no description and with 1 question marked with it

Comment: Yeah, those might be targets for clean-up and burnination.  Feel free to ask another meta question about if and how they should be cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through this list and think about this :)